# Send a pdf file using telegram bot api

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

i am trying to send a pdf file using the url of the file and using the method "sendDocument", the problem is that i cant access the file directly because of the server where its stored. I tried to use the answer provided in this post:
[readFileSync from an URL for Twitter media - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586522/readfilesync-from-an-url-for-twitter-media-node-js)

It works, but the file is send as "file.doc". If i change the extension to pdf, it is the correct file. Is there any extra step i need to do to send the file with the correct name and extension, or is there another way i can achieve what i need?

***EDIT:*** The code i am using to get the pdf looks exactly like the code in the anwser of the post i provided:

```
function getImage(url, callback) {
https.get(url, res => {
    // Initialise an array
    const bufs = [];

    // Add the data to the buffer collection
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        bufs.push(chunk)
    });

    // This signifies the end of a request
    res.on('end', function () {
        // We can join all of the 'chunks' of the image together
        const data = Buffer.concat(bufs);

        // Then we can call our callback.
        callback(null, data);
    });
})
// Inform the callback of the error.
.on('error', callback);
}
```

To send the file i use something like this:

```
getImage(url, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    bot.sendDocument(
        msg.chat.id,
        data,
    );
})
```

Comment: Can you please add your sample code!?

Comment: Hi, i added some code on the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I am using the telebot api (sorry for not mentionig that detail, but i did not knew it, i did not make the project).

I used the following line to send the file:

```
bot.sendDocument(chat_id, data, {fileName: 'file.pdf'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the file name and file type by using this code:

```
const fileOptions = {
  // Explicitly specify the file name.
  filename: 'mypdf.pdf',
  // Explicitly specify the MIME type.
  contentType: 'application/pdf',
};
```

Full function:

```
 getImage("https://your.url/yourfile.pdf", function(err, data){
  if(err){
      throw new Error(err);
  }

      const fileOptions = {
        // Explicitly specify the file name.
        filename: 'mypdf.pdf',
        // Explicitly specify the MIME type.
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
      };
      bot.sendDocument(msg.chat.id, data, {}, fileOptions);
});
```

**NOTE:** You **MUST** provide an empty object `({})` in place of Additional Telegram query options, if you have no query options to specify. For example,

// **WRONG!**
// '*fileOptions*' will be taken as additional Telegram query options!!!

```
bot.sendAudio(chatId, data, fileOptions);
```

// **RIGHT!**

```
bot.sendAudio(chatId, data, {}, fileOptions);
```

More informations here: 
https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/usage.md#sending-files

Comment: Thak you for your answer @mrblue. I tried the code but it keeps sending the file as 'file.doc'

Comment: That's weird because I've tested this code and it's working fine for me. Maybe it's because of the URL?

Comment: I'm not sure, i tried the getImage method with a picture stored in the same server, and it woked as expected