# Use URL file when uploading to Stripe.fileUploads

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to [upload an identity document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/create?lang=node) to Stripe from a URL image.
However, I'm getting this error back...

```
Error: We don't currently support that file type. Try uploading a file with one of the following mimetypes: image/jpeg, image/png
```

Here is my code...

```
stripe.fileUploads.create({
          purpose: 'identity_document',
          file: {
            data: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/laundry-llama.appspot.com/o/SudsterIDs%2FtZehZpG4wiTC7WArdaeaVsZGxuA3%2FIDBack?alt=media&token=e5c045b2-9bab-43a5-92ab-d19105dad954",
            name: 'FileName',
            type: 'image/jpeg'
          }
        }, {
          stripe_account: "acct_0000000000"
        })
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? In the documentation example, it uses a local file and not a URL.

Comment: Hi Nackshon, did you find a solution to this? Would be amazing if you could share it. Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly the issue; it needs to be the raw file data itself, not a url. I'd recommend requesting that file yourself, storing its data, and then sending that along to stripe. This should be a good starting point: [readFileSync from an URL for Twitter media - node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586522/readfilesync-from-an-url-for-twitter-media-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

```
 let fp = fs.readFileSync("./public/images/fileUploadDoc.png");
    let docUpload = await stripe.fileUploads.create({
        file: {
        data: fp,
        name: "fileUploadDoc.png",
        type: "application/octet-stream",
        },
        purpose: "identity_document",
        });
```

Check for file type also. Thanks.